# Create a function that returns a data frame from CSV files?

Tags: r, function, csv, merge

I am trying to make a function that outputs a dataframe from 8 different CSV files. They all have the same variables and same sort of data. The only difference in them is the year. I have tried to write out the function, but I can't seem to make it work. I am thinking a lapply woulf work, but I am not sure how to incorporate it.

These are the instructions:
Write a function named 'air' that takes a 'year' argument and returns a data.frame containing that data for that year, suppressing the automatic conversion to factors.

```
path <- "C:/Users/Lacy Macc/Downloads/adviz/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
for(y in files)
 air <- function(year){
   if (!exists(""))
     }
 }
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path = path, pattern = 'csv$'), read.csv))`, though you might want to subset the vector of files to those you want per your instructions.

Comment: Would I add that into the function or would it just be something on its own?

Comment: That code would read all the files in the `path` folder and combine them into a single dataframe. But based on the instructions, that's not what you need, you want to only read and return the data corresponding to the correct year. Can you give an example of the naming scheme for the files and how that corresponds to the year?

Comment: @lacymacc5552 Either way. I usually use it on its own, as I don't find myself rereading CSVs, but you could put it in a function if you like.

Comment: @Marius 

This is what the files look like in the csv format ....................................

> files
[1] "ad_viz_plotval_data-2009.csv" "ad_viz_plotval_data-2010.csv"
[3] "ad_viz_plotval_data-2011.csv" "ad_viz_plotval_data-2012.csv"
[5] "ad_viz_plotval_data-2013.csv" "ad_viz_plotval_data-2014.csv"
[7] "ad_viz_plotval_data-2015.csv" "ad_viz_plotval_data-2016.csv"

Comment: If you know the naming scheme is fixed, then you can find the filename using something like `paste0("C:/path/to/folder/", "ad_viz_plotval_data-", year, ".csv")`, no need to search through the output of `list.files`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you, Marius!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the filenames of each file varied, you might need to use `list.files` and search through the filenames to identify one matching the year. But with a fixed filename scheme, all you need to do is insert the year at the appropriate point in the filename:

```
path <- "C:/Users/Lacy Macc/Downloads/adviz/"
year <- 2013
file_path <- paste0(path, "ad_viz_plotval_data-", year, ".csv")
```

I have left out the full details of how to convert this into a function that takes in the year as I suspect this might be a homework Q.